# showPopup is not a function (Angular)

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have a method that shows a popup

Here is a class for EmployeePopup

```
  export class EmployeePopup {
    // Angular workaround
    public showPopup: (employeeId: string) => Promise<void>;

    constructor() {}

    public show(employee: Employee): Promise<void> {
        return this.showPopup(employee.id);
    }
}
```

Here is the code where I try to call it

```
private showEmployee(options: {
        employee: Employee;
        changeUrl?: boolean;
    }): void {
        if (options.changeUrl) {
            const employeeIdKey = this.getEmployeeIdUrlKey();
            const query = QueryParser.buildQueryString([
                { key: employeeIdKey, value: options.employee.id },
            ]);
            UserHistory.set(query);
        }

        this.employeePopup.show(options.employee).then(() => {
            if (this.orgChart.visible) {
                this.orgChart.sendToBack();
            }
        });
    }
```

But in this call shows an error in the console

> Uncaught TypeError: this.showPopup is not a function
> at push../js/modules/popup/employee/EmployeePopup.ts.EmployeePopup.show
> (EmployeePopup.ts:12:21)
> at push../js/modules/page/employee/EmployeeController.ts.EmployeeController.showEmployee
> (EmployeeController.ts:184:28)
> at push../js/modules/page/employee/EmployeeController.ts.EmployeeController.getAndShowEmployee
> (EmployeeController.ts:138:18)

How I can fix this?

Comment: You never define `showPopup` to be a function?

Answer (score 2):

I believe the issue is that you are not initializing `showPopup`. Could you try doing this:

```
public async showPopup(employeeId: string): Promise<void> {
    return;
}
```

And see if it works.

Comment: yes, this fixed error